# Write two versions of class with two different super classes without violating DRY?

Tags: python

I have a class called `LimitedDict` which is a dictionary that limits the number of entries it can contain by deleting old entries when a new one is added. It currently inherits from Python's `dict` class. I now need the exact same class, only I want it to inherit from `defaultdict` so that it has default values. How can I do this without just copying and pasting code?

I've thought of making it a wrapper, but that creates a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: Agree with Doc Brown, I have an implementation below using MutableMapping as an abstract base class: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/276704/102438

Answer (score 30):

Deriving a class "LimitedDict" from `dict` with the described behaviour will probably violate the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#A_typical_violation). Most code using dictionaries will expect that all data you put into a dict will stay in there and not vanish suddenly. So you cannot easily use a LimitedDict as a replacement for a `dict` in most places.

That's why it is not a good idea to derive such a class from `dict`, better implement it by **using** a dict. It is the old mantra: when in doubt, favor composition over inheritance. The internal "storage" attribute of your class could either be a standard `dict` or a `defaultdict`, and you can implement some mechanics to choose between those two (for example by injecting the `dict` object through the constructor), which solves your problem immediately.

You may call this "making a wrapper", and yes, you will have to add a little bit of boilerplate code, but to my experience this is a small price for the headaches you will save yourself from when you later have to maintain that code.

Comment: I would think that inheritance relationships don't matter so much in a duck-typed language - if your LimitedDict behaves like a dict, then not inheriting from dict *won't* stop you from accidentally passing it to a function that expects a normal dict. The second point (that composition makes it easier) is valid though.

Comment: (Put more simply, in a duck-typed language, I think inheritance and is-a are separate concepts)

Comment: I believe I provide a practical implementation below, please comment.

Comment: Note sure I agree on LSP.  Wikipedia article notes "then objects of type T in a program may be replaced with objects of type S without altering any of the **desirable** properties of that program".  (emphasis added).  Whether old entries are preserved, or deleted to save space, is arguably a non-essential effect and it depends on the usage as to which is "desirable".

Comment: In this specific use case, the LimitedDict should be interchangeable with a dict object. The purpose of the LimitedDict is to cap the amount of memory used. The functionality of the program doesn't depend on the limited size.

Comment: @user949300: "desirable" is a soft term, and yes, when you have a component which can either take a dict or a LimitedDict as an input, and that piece of software was written with the potential loss of elements in the container in mind, then this will probably work, of course. But only because something works does not mean it leads you to a maintainable solution. The LSP is about how to design inherited classes which can be used as a replacement for the base class (or other derived classes) in *most* cases, not in *some specially prepared* cases.

Comment: Doc Brown, why does it matter if it works in most cases or only in some "special" cases? If it only works in "most" cases, then whoever is using the class needs to be aware of the limitations. If it only works in "some" cases, then whoever is using it would still have to be aware of the limitations. I do agree though with @immibis. Doesn't seem like there are any practical differences in Python, though there are semantic ones.

Comment: @sinθ: I wrote "most cases", because someone could design a malicous class which checks the type of container explicitly and refuses to work it is something different than the standard dict. You can replace "most" by "all reasonable written", if you like. Furthermore, LSP is about obeying to contracts. Especially in Python (but also in other, stronger typed languages), contracts are often implicit. In my understanding, the implicit contract of a `dict` contains the assumption it does not loose any elements, because that's a behaviour most people would expect.

Answer (score 5):

In this *specific case*, you don't need to subclass `defaultdict` at all, because `defaultdict` is not much more than a `dict` subclass with an added [`__missing__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__).

You can simply subclass `LimitedDict` and add that method to the subclass:

```
class DefaultLimitedDict(LimitedDict):
    def __init__(self, factory, *args, **kw):
        self.default_factory = factory
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)

    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        self[key] = new_value = self.default_factory()
        return new_value
```

In a more generic situation you could move to using multiple inheritance; move your additional methods or custom behaviour to a *mix-in* class and inherit from both `dict` or `defaultdict` and your mix-in:

```
class LimitedDict(DictLimiter, dict):
    # methods will first be looked up on DictLimiter, then dict

class DefaultLimitedDict(DictLimiter, defaultdict):
    # methods will first be looked up on DictLimiter, then dict
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for something like a mixin. A mixing is like a subclass that you can apply to multiple superclasses, to create a new combined class. Since Python supports multiple inheritance, this is fairly easy to do:

```
class A(object):
  def foo(self):
    print("A::foo")
  def bar(self):
    print("A::bar")

# a variation of A
class B(A):
  def foo(self):
    print("B::foo")

# a mixin that can be applied to any A -- that is A or B
class Mixin(A):
  def foo(self):
    print("before foo")
    super(Mixin, self).foo()
  def bar(self):
    super(Mixin, self).bar()
    print("after bar")

# Mixin + A
# actually, that's the same as Mixin itself
class MixedA(Mixin, A):
  pass

# Mixin + B
class MixedB(Mixin, B):
  pass

a = MixedA()
a.foo()
a.bar()

b = MixedB()
b.foo()
b.bar()
```

Output:

```
before foo
A::foo
A::bar
after bar
before foo
B::foo
A::bar
after bar
```

which tells us that the combined classes are architectured in a manner so that the `Mixin` changes apply to both the `A` and `B` superclasses as if you had copy-pasted them.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Doc Brown on the matter of Liskov Substitution, but if you don't inherit from dict, how will you know you're supporting the right abstract interface? May I suggest using `MutableMapping` from the collections module?

The docstring for `MutableMapping` from the source looks like this:

> ```
> """A MutableMapping is a generic container for associating
> key/value pairs.
>
> This class provides concrete generic implementations of all
> methods except for __getitem__, __setitem__, __delitem__,
> __iter__, and __len__.
>
> """
> ```

Which means those magic methods are all you need to implement to get the same dict functionality. It might look something like this (tested nominally in Python 2 and 3):

```
import collections

class LimitedDict(collections.MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self, maxlen=10):
        self.maxlen = maxlen
        self.latest = collections.deque(maxlen=maxlen)
        self.data = {}
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        '''ld[i] = y'''
        item_in = key in self.data
        if len(self.latest) >= self.maxlen and not item_in:
            self.latest.pop()
        elif item_in:
            self.latest.remove(key)
        self.latest.appendleft(key)
        self.data[key] = value
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        '''del ld[i]'''
        del self.data[key]
        self.latest.remove(key) 
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key] 
    def __iter__(self):
        for key in self.latest:
            yield key 
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.latest)
```

And did not test much, but I did do this, and behaves as expected:

```
def main():
    ld = LimitedDict(3)
    ld['foo'] = 1
    print(ld['foo'])
    ld['bar'] = 2
    print(ld['bar'])
    del ld['bar']
    assert 'bar' not in ld 
    ld['bar'] = 3
    ld['foo'] = 4
    ld['baz'] = 5
    ld['quux'] = 6
    assert 'bar' not in ld
    for key, value in ld.items():
        print(key, value)
    ld.update(foo=7, bar=8, baz=9)
    try:
        del ld['quux']
    except KeyError:
        raised = True
    assert raised
    assert not isinstance(ld, dict)
```

This runs in both Python 2.6 and 3.3, and you can use e.g. `iteritems` in 2 too.

Also, `setdefault` is available, so you don't really need `defaultdict`, either. Here's the help on how it works:

```
>>> help(dict.setdefault)
Help on method_descriptor:

setdefault(...)
    D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D
```